# Nuget reference error, cannot find namespace

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, nuget

I've installed a NuGet-package required to run som code to create QR-codes. The package conflicts with system.drawing.common

> Error CS0433 The type 'PixelFormat' exists in both 'CoreCompat.System.Drawing, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c0a7ed9c2333b592' and 'System.Drawing.Common, Version=4.0.0.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'

I'm trying to solve it like this:

```
using PixelFormat = CoreCompat.System.Drawing;
```

Allthough it throws an error:

> Error CS0246 The type or namespace name 'CoreCompat' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Obviously Visual studio knows it's there somehow thoug since otherwise there would not be a conflict.

I've tried reinstalling all related NuGet-packages.

How would i go about solving this?

Comment: `CoreCompat.System.Drawing` is an assembly, not a namespace.  You should delete it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CoreCompat is an old library built to provide a `System.Drawing` compatible API that would work in Core, as originally `System.Drawing` was not supported. Since that time, Microsoft has released `System.Drawing.Common`, which is its own Core-compatible `System.Drawing` replacement API. Somehow, you have references to both in your project.

If your QR code library is using `CoreCompat`, you should really file an issue with that project to ask them to update the dependency to `System.Drawing.Common`. Or, you can make the change yourself and submit a pull request. Otherwise, or until it's corrected, you may need to find a different library to use.

It's possible the dependency is coming from somewhere else, as well. Check your own projects to ensure you're not bringing that in. Ultimately, you're simply going to have to do a little research here and see where `CoreCompat` is coming from and get rid of that.